# Rotated Header CSS3

Tags: html, css

Hello trusty StackOverflow users,

I am creating a sample webpage and was wondering how to elongate a rotated header that extends off the page in css3. I can provide more code if necessary. I would show a picture of what i am looking for but haven't accumulated enough rep (Just got enough rep to show a picture)... Thanks for any help in advance!

Here is what i want:

[image]

'h4' is the header i'm trying to elongate and here is what i have it doing now:

```
h4 {
    color: #fbff00;
    background-color: #858585;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
    float:left;
    text-align:center;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #d1cfd1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #d1cfd1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #d1cfd1;
   }
```

-Nate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uHbP8/) come close to what you want?

The idea is:

- Give the header an explicit pixel width (to manage its "size")
- Give it a negative left margin to make it hug the left edge (amount dependent on width given)
- Give it a positive left padding to let the text be positioned naturally (also dependent on width given)

Comment: One more thing: What if i wanted to compensate for a change in browser size? Would i have to use percentages?

Comment: @NathanMoraton: Unfortunately I can't think of a way that would let the size (and necessarily also the position) of the header be dependent on the page's width and at the same time keep the text centered.

Comment: Well to compensate for the size change i just upped the size of the whole body(I know that it probably isn't the best idea but it works for the time being). Thanks again for all your help Jon.